# Accessing Child Element in Xaml Control Library

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2012, controltemplate

I am making a control library in a  xaml file(library.xaml) in which i have defined all the controls and i m handling their events in .cs file named(library.cs) 
I want to access child element of resource dictionary in .cs file...i dnt knw how to do that

Here is my two files

library.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                x:Class="custom_template.library">

 <Style  x:Key="my_progressbar_primary">
  <Setter Property="Control.Template">
   <Setter.Value>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ProgressBar" >
        <Grid Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}">
                    <Rectangle  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20px"   VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"  Stroke="#ddd"  ClipToBounds="True" RadiusX="3" RadiusY="3" Style="{StaticResource style_shadow_top}"></Rectangle>
                    <Rectangle  Height="20" Width="100"   HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" RadiusX="3" RadiusY="3" Style="{StaticResource style_shadow_top_primary}"></Rectangle>
         </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
   </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

library.cs

```
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Timers;

  namespace custom_template
  {
   partial class library
   {
    private void xxx()
    {

    }
   }
 }
```

Problem: I Want to change the width of rectangle in xxx() method.....but i m not able to access it...i have also tried accessing rectangle using findname but it is not working
help me out

Answer (score -1):

Have some name to your rectangle,

```
<Rectangle x:Name="rect"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20px"   VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"  Stroke="#ddd"  ClipToBounds="True" RadiusX="3" RadiusY="3" Style="{StaticResource style_shadow_top}"></Rectangle>
```

and do the following in library class,

```
private void xxx()
{
     if (Template != null)
     {
         var rect = (Rectangle)Template.FindName("rect", this);
         //Where this is the Instance of ProgressBar.
         //check the rect is not null and change the width of rect here... 
     }
}
```

**Update:**

```
In your `OnApplyTemplate` of your custom control..

protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
{
    RectProperty = GetTemplateChild("rect") as Rectangle;
    //RectProperty is your property
}
```

Comment: i have already tried this but i m getting an error that  "name Template does not exist in current context". Is there some another way to access it??

Comment: As i Previously mentioned i dont want to use event and event handler

Comment: So my option to have a property in your custom control. Set that property in the OnApplyTemplate override..